# How do I trust a self signed certificate from an electron app?

Tags: ssl, https, electron, self-signed

I have an electron app that syncs with a server I own at a https://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:port that has a self signed certificate. How can I trust that certificate from my electron app?

Right now I get:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

Comment: related: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1956

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to put the following code into your "shell" (core electron init) file:

```js
// SSL/TSL: this is the self signed certificate support
app.on('certificate-error', (event, webContents, url, error, certificate, callback) => {
    // On certificate error we disable default behaviour (stop loading the page)
    // and we then say "it is all fine - true" to the callback
    event.preventDefault();
    callback(true);
});
```

This would allow insecure (invalid) certificates like self-signed one.

⚠ Please note that **this is NOT a secure way** of connecting to the server.

For more, check the documentation:
https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#event-certificate-error

Comment: This is only valid if the request comes from the `renderer` process, isn't it? Is there a way to intercept requests from `request` or `axios` on the `main` process?

Comment: Recommend to add a regex check for the specific URL for extra security, e.g. `if (/xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx/g.test(url)) { ... }`

Answer (score 9):

Subscribe to the [`certificate-error`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#event-certificate-error) event emitted by the `app` module and verify your self signed cert in the event handler.

Answer (score 6):

Try this if `'certificate-error'` event doesn't work:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEV') {
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;
}
```

Comment: This one seems to be the solution for recent versions of node (10.13.0 for me)

Comment: Same for me. I found the `certificate-error` approach did not work. The env approach did.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you can also configure this on the BrowserWindow side of your electron startup script via setCertificateVerifyProc(). I couldn't get any of the other above methods to work, at least in Electron 10.4.4.

e.g.

```
var win = new BrowserWindow({
    ...
});

win.webContents.session.setCertificateVerifyProc((request, callback) => {
    var { hostname, certificate, validatedCertificate, verificationResult, errorCode } = request;

    // Calling callback(0) accepts the certificate, calling callback(-2) rejects it.
    if (isNotMyCertificate(certificate)) { callback(-2); return; }

    callback(0);
  });
```

Where isNotMyCertificate() verifies that the data in certificate is yours. console.log() it to discover the certificate structure. It gives you a bit more control over security than blanket allowing all certificates.

See setCertificateVerifyProc() in  https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/session#sessetcertificateverifyprocproc
for more details.

Answer (score 3):

In the app entry file, do:

```js
const { app } = require('electron')

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-certificate-errors')
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me with electron 18

Comment: when I applied above solution then I am getting 404 error from server. any idea?