# Connecting socket.io over https server

Tags: node.js, electron, socket.io-1.0

I am using electron js as client and created a nodejs server on port 3000 with my own signed https certificate.
But when i tried to connect to my socket server from client using

```
io.connect("https://localhost:3000")
```

I am getting error as:-

```
ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

Please save my day.Thanks in advance!!!

Server side code

```
var apps = require("express")()
if (isUseHTTPs) {
  app = server.createServer(options, apps);
} else {
  app = server.createServer(apps);
}


const io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
   socket.emit("getData",(data)=>{
         console.log(data);
    })
})

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, resolveURL('fake-keys/privatekey.pem'))),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, resolveURL('fake-keys/certificate.pem')))
};
```

Basically i want to create a video or audio confrencing system but it requires https secured server so i cant use http

Comment: Try out using `wss` instead of `https`

Comment: same error continue @mbrandau

Comment: Can you show the server-side code then?

Comment: edited @mbrandau

Comment: I don't see any socket.io code there...

Comment: sorry for that...i agve you only server creating code not socket...i have edited please look over again @mbrandau

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165165/discussion-between-mbrandau-and-lal-rishav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably is, that electron does not trust your certificates. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38989441/5133130

Comment: thanx a lot it helped me..u saved my day