# How do I trust a self signed certificate from an electron app from the main process, using the `electron.net` API?

Tags: ssl, https, electron, self-signed, certificate-authority

The goal is to customise certificate validation from within the main process of an electron app, for the use with self-signed certificates and non-matching hostnames in development and testing conditions. The [`electron.net`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/net) API provides the option to supply a [`Session`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/session) object, which has a [`setCertificateVerifyProc`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/session#sessetcertificateverifyprocproc) method. However, the callback I register using that method never gets called.

There is a related question here: [How do I trust a self signed certificate from an electron app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986692/how-do-i-trust-a-self-signed-certificate-from-an-electron-app)
However, the accepted answer from that question only works in a render process. Indeed, on the main process, the event `certificate-error` is never issued.