# How to change the http:\\localhost:8001 to HTTPS for Electron .Net Core application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, electron

Currently, i have developed a.Net Core MVC application which includes the feature for screen sharing using the Janus webrtc.

The Janus WebRtc screen sharing will only work with the application running in HTTPS.

Now I have converted the MVC app to a desktop application using Electron. But the screen sharing is not working.

So kindly share some thoughts on this.

Comment: Have you hosted the application in 443 port, if so u have to create the dummy certificate and attach to browser. for reference please look in to https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-host-webapp-in-iis-100

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986692/how-do-i-trust-a-self-signed-certificate-from-an-electron-app